# Directory disappeared while renaming

Tags: windows-7, rename

I was just renaming a directory on my desktop using standard GUI procedure and it disappeared. I checked the usual things like recycle bin, hidden file settings, system file hiding and so on but it's still not there. I also can't find it using cmd.

Directory's previous name was microcontrollers and I changer it to Propeller, so there shouldn't be any legal characters and so on.

In the directory I had several PDF files, if that matters.
So what should I do? Currently my available options are to attempt to access the disk from another windows installation of to try to access it using ntfs-3g from GNU/Linux, but I'm afraid that I'll do something to make things even worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is a file system error.  Try running chkdsk to see if it finds anything wrong.

```
chkdsk /F C:
```

You should get this message:

```
Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Would you like to schedule this volume to be
checked the next time the system restarts? (Y/N)
```

It will run the next time you reboot your computer and fix any filesystem errors.

Note:  If your main hard drive is not `C:`, change it accordingly.

Comment: It solved the problem. I now had two directories with a same name and one had the data of the lost directory. I managed to rename it without any problems.